# html anchor tags with additional/custom http header support

Tags: html, anchor

There are lots of revision happened for HTML and now its in 5th version. Why till now the anchor tag `(<a>)` have not supporting additional http Header.

What is the reason to not support http headers on anchor tag ??

Comment: what exactly you require?

Comment: Not solution to add custom header using JavaScript.. i am trying to understand why html doesnt defined something to support passing additional headers while using anchor tag

Comment: Header info is something larger property/properties which may be overhead to the tag to specify

Comment: you mean its a technical difficulty to define some markup definition to include additional parameters to pass while making a request ?? I cant belive

Comment: @Ysak same things can be achieved with JS, why you want it in HTML5.